# Avoiding "the double import trap" when writing Python package

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I am trying to build a Python package [my first] with what seems to be standard directory structure:

```
- myFolder > 
   - .git > 
   - doc > 
   - test > 
   - packagename > 
      - __init__.py
      - file1.py
      - file2.py
      - file3.py
   - setup.py
   - README
```

## package structure

My `setup.py` file looks something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='myFolder.py',
      version="0.0.1",
      description='packagename.py: a description',
      author='bashfuloctopus',
      packages=['packagename'],
      platforms=['any'])
```

My `__init__.py` file looks something like

```
import packagename.file1 as file1
import packagenmae.file2 as file2
```

Now, in `file2.py` I would like to use methods from `file3.py` and so `file2` contains a line

```
import packagename.file3 as file3
```

## installing the package

To install the package, I open up a command line, change the working directory to `myFolder/`and run `python setup.py install`

## loading the package

To test how the install went, I open up python 3.5 from the command line and run `import packagename`.

## the problem

The problem I have arises from the fact that there are now two copies of `file3` that have been loaded into Python. The first is `packagename.file3`, as expected; however, there is a second copy that appears as `packagename.file2.file3`.

I have looked through SO to resolve this and have not found anything (though perhaps I was searching with the wrong keywords). I *did* manage to find [this blog article](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap%20this%20blog%20article) about the double import trap, but was not able to resolve my issue with it.

I have tried several different things, including changing the working directory that I'm installing the package from; using `import packagename.file3` instead of `import packagename.file3 as file`; and excluding the `import ... file3` from `file2.py` altogether, in the hope that it would already be in the namespace. Unfortunately, none of these seem to work.

Any help you could provide would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have the double import trap in your example... you have just introduced the `file3` module in 2 different namespaces but they both refer to the same module. What's the issue with this? You will find this in all the system libraries, e.g. `os` has `os.sys` which is just the `sys` module.

Comment: I had somehow thought that it was creating two copies of the same module. Instead, it seems, that it's two references to the same object. Thanks for clearing this up!